# Data got committed in another/same session, cannot update row (Oracle SQL Developer)

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I occasionally get this error when i try to update a record through the grid.

```
One error saving changes to table "SCHEMA"."TABLENAME":
Row 3: Data got committed in another/same session, cannot update row.
```

Looked up at OTN but no solution yet given.

Tried to disable the option **Post edits on row change** but still no luck.

There is a known solution for setting the field to **NULL** through the SQL Worksheet but it's surely a pain.

Comment: are you sure you have the latest SQL Developer?

Comment: i previously used something like 2.xx.xxx and now I have upgraded to version 3.1.07 Build MAIN-07.42 and still get the same error

Answer (score 36, accepted):

It could be that your table is created with NOROWDEPENDENCIES so row-level dependency tracking is turned off, and SQL Developer is configured to "Use ORA_ROWSCN for DataEditor insert and update statements".

Either uncheck the ORA_ROWSCN option, or recreate the table with ROWDEPENDENCIES.

Comment: How do I uncheck this option, @DavidAldridge ? I have no idea how to find it.

Comment: It's somewhere in the preferences ... can't remember where and I don't have SQL Developer installed anymore

Comment: Select Tools from the menu bar -> Preferences -> Database -> ObjectViewer, There a check box "Use ORA_ROWSCN for DataEditor insert and update statements" here a image http://postimg.org/image/8z2fkqb4z/

Comment: Note that after you turn of ORA_ROWSCN, you must exit Oracle SQL developer, and then restart it. Then I was allowed to delete the records that were getting this error.

Comment: I have version 4.1.5.21 and I've unchecked this option, and restarted and it still doesn't seem to fix the issue?  Help.

Answer (score 5):

Just simply run simple update command and set your cplumn to null. Then try to update with your real value. It will definitely work.

Answer (score 2):

"One error saving changes to table "SCHEMA"."TABLENAME":
Row XX: Data got committed in another/same session, cannot update row."

Got this error with SQL developer when commiting changes in multiple rows,
but not when commiting a single row.

I fixed it going to:

Tools menu -> Preferences -> Database -> ObjectViewer

and check: "Post edits on row change"

However, every time I navigate to another row takes some time (less than a second with the DB I am working on).
For what I could understand from other posts the remote DB in my session is being updated (but not comitted to all sessions) every time I change row.
However to commit to all session it is needed to explicitly commit.

Meanwhile I tried, as others suggested, to:

Tools menu -> Preferences -> Database -> ObjectViewer

uncheck "Use ORA_ROWSCN for DataEditor insert and update statements" option
(and also leave uncheck: "Post edits on row change")

This also works, but it is faster.
It guess that now the update is only local. Remote DB is not updated every time I navigate to another row.
It is needed to commit to update remote DB, but now with no errors.

I read that this solution does not worked for all.
It worked in my case with:

SQL developer Version: 17.4.1.054, Build 054.0712

ODAC 12.2c Release 1 and Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio (12.2.0.1.0) (32-bit)
(http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/utilsoft-086879.html)

Remote DB server version: Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production

Answer (score -1):

I ran into this problem as well while running a stored procedure.  My solution fell inline with the above answers.  Before updating the row that I wanted to the value I wanted, I added an update line that first updated the column to null.  The following line then updated the column to the value that I wanted.  I did this in addition to unchecking the box for ORA_ROWSCN.

UPDATE TEST_LOCATION SET STATUS = NULL WHERE FULL_NAME = SITE_FULL_NAME;

UPDATE TEST_LOCATION SET STATUS = CAST(STATUS_IN AS INTEGER) WHERE FULL_NAME = SITE_FULL_NAME;